# Using variables in Laravel to set dynamic keywords meta

Tags: laravel

I am trying to set dynamic keywords meta. I am looking for a way to make this:

```
    @foreach($video->tags as $tag)

    <!-- Here I want to set $tag(s) separated by "," as a string $tags_list -->

    @endforeach
    @section('keywords', $tags_list)
```

I am not used to Laravel, I tried using PHP with implode but I always get syntax errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

**Edit:**

Based on @Paras's suggestion, using

```
    @section('keywords', $video->tags->pluck('name')->all())
```

gives

```
    [2018-10-19 00:28:47] production.ERROR: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: /home/website/video/resources/views/video.blade.php) {"userId":1,"email":"user@email.net","exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: /home/website/video/resources/views/video.blade.php) at /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php:577, ErrorException(code: 0): htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given at /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php:577)
    [stacktrace]
    #0 /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/PhpEngine.php(45): Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\CompilerEngine->handleViewException(Object(ErrorException), 0)
    #1 /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(59): Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\PhpEngine->evaluatePath('/home/website/vide...', Array)
    #2 /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(137): Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\CompilerEngine->get('/home/website/vide...', Array)
    #3 /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(120): Illuminate\\View\\View->getContents()
    #4 /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(85): Illuminate\\View\\View->renderContents()
    #5 /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Response.php(39): Illuminate\\View\\View->render()
    #6 /home/website/video/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php(201): Illuminate\\Http\\Response->setContent(Object(Illuminate\\View\\View))
    #7 /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(711): Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Response->__construct(Object(Illuminate\\View\\View))
    #8 /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(685): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router::toResponse(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\View\\View))
    #9 /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(645): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->prepareResponse(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\View\\View))
    #10 /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #11 /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(41): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #12 /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
    #13 /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #14 /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(67): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #15 /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
    #16 /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #17 /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #18 /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
    #19 /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #20 /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(63): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #21 /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
    #22 /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #23 /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #24 /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
    #25 /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #26 /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(59): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #27 /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
    #28 /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #29 /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #30 /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(647): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
    #31 /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(622): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #32 /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(588): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route))
    #33 /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(577): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #34 /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(176): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #35 /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #36 /home/website/video/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php(56): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #37 /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
    #38 /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #39 /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(30): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #40 /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
    #41 /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #42 /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(30): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #43 /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
    #44 /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #45 /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #46 /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
    #47 /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #48 /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(46): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #49 /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
    #50 /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #51 /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #52 /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(151): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
    #53 /home/website/video/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #54 /home/website/public_html/index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
    #55 {main}
    "}
```

In front.blade.php I have

```
<meta name="keywords" content="@yield('keywords')">
```

In video.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.front')
@section('keywords', $keywords_string)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `$video->tags` is a collection and you need the name field, use:

```
@section('keywords', implode(", ", $video->tags->pluck('name')->all()))
```

Comment: `$video->tags` are objects. I need to do (as far as I understood) `($video->tags)->name` to get the actual tag as a string.
Your suggestion gave an empty `[]`

Comment: Is `$video->tags` a collection?

Comment: Yes it is a collection.

Comment: Using `@section('keywords', $video->tags->pluck('name')->all())` I got the following error `"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`

I have the following in my code and tags are appearing normally. I'm definitely missing something basic
`@if(count($video->tags))`
`@foreach($video->tags as $tag)`
`<a href="{{ url('tag/'.$tag->id) }}" >{{ $tag->name }}</a>`
`@endforeach`
`@endif`

Comment: Paste the complete stack trace along with the keywords section code

Comment: Aah you dont need an array in the keywords section, you need a string. Updated my answer

Comment: That is exactly what I was missing! Thank you very much!!